# hook_update a rule configuration?

Tags: 7, commerce, rules, updating

I would like to update a payment method settings. As I understand, the settings are inside a RulesReactionRule.

Is it possible to modify the configuration of a RulesReactionRule using a hook_update ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found how to export the Drupal commerce payment method settings using commerce_features and the patch: https://www.drupal.org/node/1973098#comment-10559856